# how to solve: symbol(s) not found for architecture in macOS bundle

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, unity-game-engine

Im writing simple wrapper for loading leaderboards from game center and it's working like a charm on iOS, but while i build my app on macOS i'm getting this error:

```
  "_gameCenter_loadLeaderboard", referenced from:
      _LeaderboardWrapper_gameCenter_loadLeaderboard_m1E818D39D7E09691764495F877AE9D990EC4D432 in F9507B415CD33260EA533B953F7CF7A8.o
     (maybe you meant: _LeaderboardWrapper_gameCenter_loadLeaderboard_m1E818D39D7E09691764495F877AE9D990EC4D432)
  "_gameCenter_setLoadLeaderboardCallbackHandler", referenced from:
      _LeaderboardWrapper_gameCenter_setLoadLeaderboardCallbackHandler_m622CA920AA696EFA52E1BA9706D4A1087FA4F1FF in F9507B415CD33260EA533B953F7CF7A8.o
     (maybe you meant: _LeaderboardWrapper_gameCenter_setLoadLeaderboardCallbackHandler_m622CA920AA696EFA52E1BA9706D4A1087FA4F1FF)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_gameCenter_loadLeaderboard", referenced from:
      _LeaderboardWrapper_gameCenter_loadLeaderboard_m1E818D39D7E09691764495F877AE9D990EC4D432 in E59781FE06F50F58456801B2C8EBD151.o
     (maybe you meant: _LeaderboardWrapper_gameCenter_loadLeaderboard_m1E818D39D7E09691764495F877AE9D990EC4D432)
  "_gameCenter_setLoadLeaderboardCallbackHandler", referenced from:
      _LeaderboardWrapper_gameCenter_setLoadLeaderboardCallbackHandler_m622CA920AA696EFA52E1BA9706D4A1087FA4F1FF in E59781FE06F50F58456801B2C8EBD151.o
     (maybe you meant: _LeaderboardWrapper_gameCenter_setLoadLeaderboardCallbackHandler_m622CA920AA696EFA52E1BA9706D4A1087FA4F1FF)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

my LeaderboardWrapper.h looks like:

```
    void gameCenter_setLoadLeaderboardCallbackHandler(GameCenter_LoadLeaderboardCallback handler);
    void gameCenter_loadLeaderboard(const char* leaderboardId);

enum GameCenterLoadLeaderboardError
{
    GCLoadLeaderboard_NoError = 0,
    GCLoadLeaderboard_CallbackHandlerNotSet,
    GCLoadLeaderboard_ServiceError,
    GCLoadLeaderboard_LeaderboardNotFound
};
```

and LeaderboardWrapper.m:

```
#import "LeaderboardWrapper.h"
#import <GameKit/GameKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

GameCenter_LoadLeaderboardCallback _gameCenterLoadLeaderboardCallbackHandler = NULL;
    
void gameCenter_setLoadLeaderboardCallbackHandler(GameCenter_LoadLeaderboardCallback handler)
{
    _gameCenterLoadLeaderboardCallbackHandler = handler;
}

void gameCenter_loadLeaderboard(const char* leaderboardId)
{
    if(_gameCenterLoadLeaderboardCallbackHandler == NULL)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary* result = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        result[@"LeaderboardId"] = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:leaderboardId];
        result[@"Sucess"] = [NSNumber numberWithBool:false];
        result[@"Error"] = [NSNumber numberWithInt:GCLoadLeaderboard_CallbackHandlerNotSet];
        _gameCenterLoadLeaderboardCallbackHandler([makeResultString(result) UTF8String]);
        return;
    }
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
    
}
#endif
```

Can anyone tell me what im doing wrong?

Comment: "what im doing wrong?"  1. You use the objective-c tag but don't seem to show one or more lines of code for it.  2. You don't tell at which line you get an error?

Comment: if(_gameCenterLoadLeaderboardCallbackHandler == NULL)  calling nil handler later??? Error has underscore _gameCenter_loadLeaderboard